# Thread Safety of Stream.Write method

Tags: .net, stream

MSDN documentation says that instance methods, which includes Stream.Write, of Stream class are not guaranteed to be thread-safe but what does it mean? What will happen if one thread tries to call Stream.Write on a Stream object before other thread haven't returned from the same method on same object? Will an exception be thrown, or the object will queue the data to send according to the order of threads? Some say it is ok to call without a locking mechanism. Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you should never call instance methods such as Read and Write on the same instance of Stream from different threads at the same time. You will get unexpected behavior. In some cases an exception might be thrown, in other your data might be corrupted and in other it might even work (if you are lucky enough).

You need to always synchronize access to such shared resources using proper locking mechanisms if you intend to use them from multiple threads.

Comment: Can we generalize this to all instance methods such that we have to use locking if we will make a multithreaded call to an object's non-static method or locking is only needed for shared resources such as network stream or file access? It would be nice to get an answer from someone who tried and experienced these things(to be sure) because I also know that it is best to always use locking mechanism. Thanks

Comment: @Alp: It is possible to make a class such that it is synchronised properly entirely internally and would hence be thread-safe. For such a class, no, you would not need to use external locking. For most use-cases though it is much simpler to implement the locking externally, and in most cases required for proper operation (for instance, locking between a read and a write to a `List<T>` element to ensure atomicity). `Read`/`Write` are also possibly internally synchronised, but they aren't guaranteed to read/write all the data given, so external locking is still required for the entire operation.

Comment: @Alp Hancioglu, no we cannot generalize. That's why all .NET Framework methods are documented and normally should explicitly state whether they are designed to be thread safe or not.

Comment: I think there's a missing "at the same time" somewhere in the answer. Multiple threads is almost never a problem as long as only one is there *at a time*

Comment: @Matthew in the general-case, internal locking does not, by itself, provide safety. This applies especially to streams, since you can't predict whether Read will read all the data you need, and you really don't want another thread stealing the second half of "your" data. Hence you need to lock for an *operation*, which is almost always more than one methid call. Seeking would be another example; if you seek then write, you don't know if another thread or in and stomped on things before you.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, good point about *at the same time*. I have edited my answer to taker it into account as it is important.

Comment: @Marc: Which is exactly the case I highlighted in the last sentence of my comment. Still, there are classes out there that will become internally inconsistent if called from multiple threads, and avoiding that will cause some (certainly not all, or even most) classes to become entirely usable in a multithreaded system without further locking. It all depends on what the class needs to do. If `Stream` did provide better guarantees around `Write` for instance, then it could be used this way for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Write is abstract method, which means that behavior of that method is defined in Stream's subclasses. Some of Stream's subclasses could provide thread-safe Write methods, while others wouldn't. So you can't say how Stream will behave if you call it's Write method from different threads concurrently, unless you know what specific Thread subclass you're dealing with.

So you should use locking when working with Stream objects, since MSDN says that Stream's methods are not guaranteed to be thread-safe, so there are probably Streams that could break when called concurrently.

But if you're explicitly using specific Stream's subclasses, and you know that it's thread-safe, then there is no need for locking.